# codeigniter Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: codeigniter, foreach

I have a full working code with retrieve insert update and delete data to database.

All is working well, but if I delete some data, it is deleted but when direct to my view page again, then it will return "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()".

When I press again my view page link it is all normal and the data I delete is gone too, this is just happen with delete function.

Code :

Controller :

```
public function merk(){
        //$data["result"] = $this->modelAdminMerk->getMerk();
        $data["totalRows"] = $this->modelAdminMerk->getTotalRows();

        $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "admin/merk";
        $config["per_page"] = 15;
        $config["total_rows"] = $data["totalRows"];
        $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
        $config["num_links"] = 10;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        if( ! $this->uri->segment(3)){
            $page = 0;
        }else{
            $page = $this->uri->segment(3);
        }

        $data["results"] = $this->modelAdminMerk->getMerkByPages($config["per_page"], $page);
        $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        $this->load->view("adminView/adminHeader");
        $this->load->view("adminView/adminMerk", $data);
        $this->load->view("adminView/adminFooter");
    }

    public function insertMerk(){
        $this->load->view("adminView/adminHeader");
        $this->load->view("adminView/adminInsertMerk");
        $this->load->view("adminView/adminFooter");
    }

    public function validateInsertMerk(){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("namaMerk", "Nama Merk", "trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[30]");

        if($this->form_validation->run()){

            $newMerk = array("merk" => $this->input->post("namaMerk"));
            $this->modelAdminMerk->insertMerk($newMerk);
            $this->merk();
        }else{
            echo "GAGAL!!!";
        }
    }

    public function editMerk($id){
        $data["merk"] = $this->modelAdminMerk->getMerkById($id);

        $this->load->view("adminView/adminHeader");
        $this->load->view("adminView/adminEditMerk", $data);
        $this->load->view("adminView/adminFooter");
    }

    function validateEditMerk(){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("namaMerk", "Nama Merk", "trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[30]");

        if($this->form_validation->run()){

            $newMerk = array("merk" => $this->input->post("namaMerk"));
            $this->modelAdminMerk->editMerk($this->input->post("id"), $newMerk);
            $this->merk();
        }else{
            echo "GAGAL";
        }

    }

    public function deleteMerk($id){
        $this->modelAdminMerk->deleteMerk($id);
        $this->merk();
    }
```

Model :

```
function getMerk(){
        $data = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM merkbarang");
        return $data->result();
    }

    function getMerkById($id){
        $this->db->where("id", $id);
        $data = $this->db->get("merkbarang");
        return $data->row();
    }

    function insertMerk($newMerk){
        $this->db->insert("merkbarang", $newMerk);
        return true;
    }

    function editMerk($id, $newMerk){
        $this->db->where("id", $id);
        $this->db->update("merkbarang", $newMerk);
        return true;
    }

    function deleteMerk($id){
        $this->db->where("id", $id);
        $this->db->delete("merkbarang");
        return true;
    }

    function getTotalRows(){
        $rows = $this->db->count_all("merkbarang");

        return $rows;
    }

    function getMerkByPages($limit, $start){
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $query = $this->db->get("merkbarang");

        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            foreach ($query->result() as $row){
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

View :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="panel panel-danger">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/insertMerk">Insert Merk</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <strong>Merk</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row" id="tabelBarang">
                        <div class="col-md-1 colBarang">
                            <strong>No</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-7 colBarang">
                            <strong>Merk</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 colBarang">
                            <strong>Action</strong>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <?php 
                        $angka = 0;
                        foreach ($results as $row){
                            $id = $row->id;
                            $merk = $row->merk;
                    ?>


                    <div class="row" id="tabelBarang">
                        <div class="col-md-1 colBarang">
                            <?php echo ++$angka; ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-7 colBarang">
                            <?php echo $merk; ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 colBarang">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" aria-label="Left Align">
                                <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/editMerk/<?php echo $id; ?>">Edit</a>                         
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 colBarang">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" aria-label="Left Align">
                                <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/deleteMerk/<?php echo $id; ?>">Delete</a>                         
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <?php 
                        }
                    ?>
                    <?php echo $links; ?>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does it work if you change `$this->merk();` to `redirect('controller/merk')`?

Comment: @JeremyJackson I was going to suggest the same thing; based on what I can see in the view, I think the controller is admin so `redirect('admin/merk');`

Comment: omg, that's a good answer, i do not think that redirect and using $this-> will be different.. problem's solved, thanks jeremy and ben

Comment: You have two different `foreach()` loops in the code of your OP.  It would have been good for you to specify exactly which one is generating the error.  Since the purpose of SO is to also help everyone who might be reading this, please fix the question and post an answer below.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad that Ben and I were able to help!

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, there is nothing wrong in your code, that should definitely work, but I would suggest you to try CI's `redirect()` method in your `delete` function

```
public function deleteMerk($id){
        $this->modelAdminMerk->deleteMerk($id);
        redirect('controllername/merk');
   }
```